# Calculate 7 day average in r

Tags: r

| Date | rate | 7_Day_rate_avg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1967-07-01 | 12.5 | N/a |
| 1967-07-02 | 12.5 | N/a |
| 1967-07-03 | 6 | N/a |
| 1967-07-04 | 8 | N/a |
| 1967-07-05 | 4 | N/a |
| 1967-07-06 | 2 | N/a |
| 1967-07-07 | 11.5 | avg |
| 1967-07-08 | 12.1 | avg |
| 1967-07-09 | 10 | avg |
| 1967-07-10 | 12.0 | avg |
| 1967-07-11 | 11.1 | avg |
| 1967-07-12 | 10 | avg |

I'm trying to calculate 7 day rate average using the "rate" column in r using rolling mean function, but I am getting a lot of errors. Not sure where to start. I want the final output to look like 7_Day_rate_avg column

`library(zoo)`
`rollmean(rate, date, 7)`

Comment: Mean of what? There are no numbers on that column. Anyway, assuming you're using the mean() function, you need to remove the NA from the 7_Day_Average column.

Comment: @Sigma thank you for reply. I use "rate" column to calculate 7 Day average ( I want the final look like 7_Day_average column)

Comment: It's sometimes better to see your code so that we can suggest corrections to it vice introducing completely different code and methods and styles. When you say *"lot of errors"*, that's a bit vague. Can you please add the code you tried and the verbatim text of the error(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming data frame `dat` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, there are several problems:

- the `library` statement must be separated from the next statement by a newline or semicolon
- `rate` is a column of a data frame, not an R variable
- the arguments to `rollmean` are wrong
- the alignment was not specified.  Since you need right alignment use `rollmeanr` with an `r` on the end.
- `fill=NA` is needed to specify that  you want to fill the first 6 values with NA values.

**1)** Putting all this together we have:

```
library(zoo)
transform(dat, avg7 = rollmeanr(rate, 7, fill = NA))
```

giving this data frame:

```
         date rate     avg7
1  1967-07-01 12.5       NA
2  1967-07-02 12.5       NA
3  1967-07-03  6.0       NA
4  1967-07-04  8.0       NA
5  1967-07-05  4.0       NA
6  1967-07-06  2.0       NA
7  1967-07-07 11.5 8.071429
8  1967-07-08 12.1 8.014286
9  1967-07-09 10.0 7.657143
10 1967-07-10 12.0 8.514286
11 1967-07-11 11.1 8.957143
12 1967-07-12 10.0 9.814286
```

**2)** Alternately convert `dat` to a zoo object and then `cbind` it to the rolling mean.  In this case we don't need `fill=` since zoo objects are automatically aligned.

```
library(zoo)
rate <- read.zoo(dat)
cbind(rate, avg7 = rollmeanr(rate, 7))
```

giving this zoo object:

```
           rate     avg7
1967-07-01 12.5       NA
1967-07-02 12.5       NA
1967-07-03  6.0       NA
1967-07-04  8.0       NA
1967-07-05  4.0       NA
1967-07-06  2.0       NA
1967-07-07 11.5 8.071429
1967-07-08 12.1 8.014286
1967-07-09 10.0 7.657143
1967-07-10 12.0 8.514286
1967-07-11 11.1 8.957143
1967-07-12 10.0 9.814286
```

### Note

`dat` in reproducible form is:

```
dat <- structure(list(date = c("1967-07-01", "1967-07-02", "1967-07-03", 
"1967-07-04", "1967-07-05", "1967-07-06", "1967-07-07", "1967-07-08", 
"1967-07-09", "1967-07-10", "1967-07-11", "1967-07-12"), rate = c(12.5, 
12.5, 6, 8, 4, 2, 11.5, 12.1, 10, 12, 11.1, 10)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```